# Node usando Axios com express, quero esperar a Promises

Tags: javascript

estou querendo esperar o valor de uma promise que esta dentro de outra

```js
const URL = 'url da api que eu quero consumir'
const AuthStr = 'meu token'

function GET (){
    axios.get(URL, { headers: { Authorization: AuthStr } })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data);
            return response.data
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('error ' + error);
        });
};

app.get("/", (request, response) => {
  let data = GET();;
  
  return response.json(data);
})
```

o problema é que eu não consigo fazer o app.get esperar o axios retorna o JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa fazer algumas modificações no seu código

Precisa avisar que a sua função é assíncrona, precisa aguardar a resposta do axios (que é assíncrono e o .then e .error são apenas formas de tratar a assincronidade) e aguardar a resposta da função GET no seu app.get

Então vai ficar da seguinte forma:

```
const URL = 'url da api que eu quero consumir'
const AuthStr = 'meu token'

async function GET (){
    const resposta = await axios.get(URL, { headers: { Authorization: AuthStr } })

    return resposta.data;
};

app.get("/", async (request, response) => {
  let data = await GET();
  
  return response.json(data);
})
```

Quando você utiliza ASYNC, você precisa avisar em todo o seu stack de chamadas que você precisa aguardar a chamada assíncrona responder, então no caso vc faz uso de await (na chamada) e de async (na função em si)

OBS: seu return no response não serve para muita coisa ai, ele está retornando para lugar nenhum. A resposta do servidor é basicamente no response, no seu caso o response.json(data)

Answer (score 0):

Olá, pelo que entendi você poderia resolver da seguinte maneira:

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/funcoes_assincronas

```
async function GET (){
    cons result = await axios.get(URL, { headers: { Authorization: AuthStr } });
    ...
    restante do código aqui...
};

....
```

Comment: olá muito obrigado era esse empurrão que eu precisava, tinha previamente testando usando async await mas não estava entendendo como fazer eu coloquei o async direto no parâmetro do express e funcionou ficou assim app.get("/", async (request, response) => { return data = await GET(); }